# Conditionally return different description text for different quantity values?

Tags: sql-server

I'm making a "search inventory" webpage and need some help.

This query works great:

```
SELECT      TOP (20) [FederalStockNum],  [Quant1]
FROM            [FederalStockCards-Detail]
WHERE        (FederalStockNum LIKE '%SEARCH-KEYWORD%')
```

It searches an inventory bringing up similar results based on the SEARCH-KEYWORD and returns something like this:

```
   ______________________________________
   | Federal Stock Number......|Quantity.|
   |_____________________________________|  
   | 5305-00-060-9995..........|.......24|
   | 5305-00-060-9996..........|.....5500|
   | MS15795-543...............|.......50|
   | MS21098-83................|........0|
```

So far so good, but this is inappropriate to expose this corporation's exact inventory. Can I change the SQL statement to return something like this?

```
   ______________________________________
   | Federal Stock Number......|Quantity.|
   |_____________________________________|  
   | 5305-00-060-9995..........|IN STOCK |
   | 5305-00-060-9996..........|IN STOCK |
   | MS15795-543...............|IN STOCK |
   | MS21098-83................|SOLD OUT |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`CASE` expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) for that:

```
SELECT      TOP (20) [FederalStockNum],  
(case when [Quant1]>0 then 'IN STOCK' else 'OUT OF STOCK' end) as Quant1
FROM            [FederalStockCards-Detail]
WHERE        (FederalStockNum LIKE '%SEARCH-KEYWORD%')
```

This would also work if you wanted to work with aggregate functions (`GROUP BY` and `SUM` for example).